# Architecture for Restricting DbContext Access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, authorization, dbcontext

I'm currently writing a rest framework,  I'd like to create a way to restrict access to certain entities not only through read but through writes as well.   Currently I've created a base DbContext, which handles the authorization like so (I've omitted some code such as option assignments because they're irrelavent to the problem):

```
public abstract class AuthorizedDbContext : DbContext
{
    //...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var constraintOptions = this._authorizationOptions.ConstraintOptions;
        constraintOptions.ApplyStaticConstraint(modelBuilder, this);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public async override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        this.VerifyResourceAccess();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected void VerifyResourceAccess()
    {
        if (false == ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
        {
            return;
        }

        //WARNING: if you don't set the change tracking behavior to no tracking, you could reload entities by accident
        var previousTrackingBehavior = this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior;
        this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        this._authorizationOptions.ContextValidator.ValidateAndThrow(this);

        this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = previousTrackingBehavior;
    }
}
```

Currently I inject a dbcontext validator which handles restricting updates and other validations on save changes.

The user has the peace of mind knowing that when using this authorized context entities will not be able to be updated without passing all of the validations the user defines in their code.

This architecture sucks, though and it seriously limits the flexability of the users code, (e.g) if a user wants to use an  IdentityDbContext this will not be possible unless I create an AuthorizedDbContext which inherits from `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`

Instead I would prefer to use a wrapper around their context. E.g

```
//Pseudo-Code
AuthorizedDbContextScope<T>: IDisposable
    where T: DbContext
{
    public void ApplyConstraints()
    {
        this._options.DynamicConstraints.Foreach(EntityFrameWorkZ.ApplyDynamicFilterFromAction)
    }
}
```

The only issues with this wrapper is that 1.  I Can't expose the DbContext Functionality, I can't override save changes in scope I must enforce the user to call save changes on the wrapper.

I could use a DynamicProxy to inherit from their DbContext in the startup, but this seems like like overkill, and it would severely slow down the project startup.

If anybody has a suggestion to how I can better universally restrict my updates, please let me know.

How can fully restrict db changes without limiting the flexability of inheritance in the user code?

Comment: This may be one of the rare case where an extra Repository/Unit of Work layer could come in handy.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, I have a Service Base architected in a way in which call the validations automatically.  I've abstracted all of the logic so that majority of service can be created through a configuration via the start up.  There are some cases where the user may need to create custom functionality which I'd like to provide them the peace of mind known they can't write anything that affect another users tenancy.  :/ I'd prefer not to create an extra layer for repositories because that will complicate the setup process, I don't think I can avoid this issue without writing proxies

Comment: But using Proxies seems to be overkill for version 1.   I have a feeling there's no simple way around this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective, but I'll give it a shot.

1. If you want to the ability to specifically define which entities you want to authorize, you could use the Authorize attribute. It's been a while since I've worked with it, but I recall the ability to customize behavior. If that doesn't work, you could write your own and decorate the entities you care about -- either use the attribute to handle authorization directly, or simply use it as an identifier and reflect on the object before you commit changes. This would give you some flexibility to customize by app domain.
2. If that doesn't work for you, how many types of contexts are you actually trying to customize? If it's two, and the nonexistent third seems far off...then yagni. If you do go with this centralize the authorization logic into a single place and create the two base classes to consume it. It's worth the mention that IdentityDbContext inherits from DbContext, so you could generalize wherever authorization winds up. Or you could use an interface if you need them to behave differently.
3. Swap out all references to DbContext with IdentityDbContext, then inherit from that with your customizations. Again, DbContext is the root of IdentityDbContext. I don't recall there being significant overhead in using one vs the other, but could depend on your domain.

All of these ideas could be limited by how your solution is architected, and if that functionality would be consumed by one application or many.

Comment: Thanks, but none of these answers will work, this architecture is created so other people can use the context in to secure their application.